# Matrices in MTLVertexDescriptor

Tags: swift, graphics, metal, metalkit, metallb

I'm trying to write vertex descriptor for my vertex shader which takes following struct as stage_in input.

```
struct VertexIn {
      float2x2 foo;
}

vertex float4 vertexShader(const VertexIn in [[stage_in]]) {...}
```

Now when defining vertex descriptor's attribute what should be the MTLVertexFormat?
`vertexDescriptor.attributes[0].format = ???`

I went through the documentation, I didn't find any enum case for Matrices. Is it fine if  say set format as `float2` and give size 2 * size of `float2`?

Answer (score 2):

According [The Metal Feature Set Tables](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Feature-Set-Tables.pdf):

---

You can declare only one argument of the vertex, fragment, or kernel function with the `[[stage_in]]` attribute. For a user-defined structure declared with the `[[stage_in]]` attribute, the members of the structure can be:

- A scalar integer or floating-point value.
- A vector of integer or floating-point values.
- An interpolant<T,P> value for fragment function input.

You cannot use the `stage_in` attribute to declare members of the structure that are **packed vectors**, **matrices**, **structures**, **bitfields**, **references** or **pointers to a type**, or arrays of scalars, vectors, or matrices.

---

Comment: Hmm nice find, somehow I missed last part, but now I wonder why matrices are not allowed as attributes? Upon more digging I found similar case for OpenGL as well, so is there HW design/optimization constraint on this?